# trade off between workers and connections

Tags: r, performance, shiny, shinyapps

I'm subscribing shinyapps.io with basic plan. So I have 3 instances, up to 3 workers per instance and up to 50 connections per workers.

I'm wondering what's the difference between

- 2 workers with 5 connections each.
- 1 worker with 10 connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is from [this help page on tuning Shiny apps](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/scaling-and-tuning.html):

> When should you worry about tuning your applications? You should
> consider tuning your applications if:
>
> Your application has several requests that are slow and you have enough concurrent usage that people’s expectations for responsiveness
> aren’t being met. For example, If your response time for some key
> calculations takes one second and you would like to make sure that the
> average response time for your application is less than two seconds,
> you will not want more than two concurrent requests per worker.
>
> **Possible Diagnosis:** The application performance might be due to R’s single threaded nature. Spreading the load across additional
> workers should alleviate the issue.
>
> **Remedy:** Consider lowering the maximum number of connections per worker, and possibly increasing the maximum number of workers.
> Also consider adding additional Application Instances and aggressively
> scaling them by tweaking the Instance Load Factor to a lower
> percentage.

The answer to your question is probably dependent on your apps. If you have a relatively simple app with fast calculations and relatively few concurrent users, you probably won't notice a difference between your two scenarios. However, if you have complex apps as described in the help page, you might notice that having more workers (i.e., more individual threads sending requests to the R server) will improve user experience.

In my experience, where I tend to have complex apps with but with few (<10) concurrent users, I haven't noticed a difference from the limited tuning I've done.

Comment: @speedy, Hope it was helpful. If so, don't forget to upvote and/or accept.